# trying to iterate over a selected elements and alert the pageX event prop. But returns undefined

Tags: jquery

I am getting cannot read property pageX of undefined.

```
        <div id="subContainer">
            <div>0</div>
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
       </div>


       <script>
            $('#subContainer div').each(function ()  {

            $(this).bind('click', function(event)  {

            alert($(this).event.pageX);

             });

        </script>
```

Could somebody please tell me how I can do it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general your code is working, but it's not a good idea to loop elements to attach events. Just do it directly. And it is just `event.pageX`, because it is stored in the event object, not in the element.

```js
$('#subContainer div').on('click', function(event) {
    alert(event.pageX);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="subContainer">
  <div>0</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

The code above does exactly the same as this below, exect that you don't need a `each` loop. **You should really use the above version!**

```
$('#subContainer div').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function(event) {
        alert(event.pageX);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your timely response, but will that iterate over  the divs?

Comment: No, you don't need to iterate the divs in your example. Just bind the `click` event all elements at once @pedroyanky

Comment: but hope you understand that my intention was to alert the coordinates of the individual divs in the parent? @eisbehr

Comment: Yes, and my example does exactly this. ;) Just try my example code above. @pedroyanky

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you, that my code is exactly the same as doing it with a loop. @pedroyanky

Comment: the each code worked very fine. But the first one didn't work at all. am sure something is missing . Could you please check it out again?

Comment: Sorry, but if the first code is not working for you, you did something wrong. The two examples **has exactly the same result**. Check this jsfiddle, you will get two `alerts` on `click` with exactly the same values: https://jsfiddle.net/rcL3f917/ @pedroyanky

Comment: @Eisbehr.You are right, thank you very much. plus you have be very helpful all the time.

Comment: but could you please show some resources that might help educate me more on how these things with jquery works?

Comment: The best place for me is the official jQuery documentation, there you find examples for every function too. https://api.jquery.com @pedroyanky